# Batch files with timeout with no press any key to continue

Tags: batch-file

When writing a batch file to change my IP Address to Static I have created this working script but right now it shows

> ```
> Changing IP address  
> Waiting for "2" seconds and press any key to continue    
> Changing Gateway      
> Waiting for "2" seconds and press any key to continue   
> Changing Subnet   
> waiting for "2" seconds and press any key to continue
> ```

The way I want it to show is

> ```
> Changing IP address    
> Sits 2 seconds with no display of text  
> Changing Gateway  
> Sits 2 seconds with no display of text  
> Changing subnet  
> Sits 2 seconds with no display of text
> ```

Right now I'm using the timeout command

Below is a snippet of code

```
@ECHO IP Address Changed  
timeout 2  
@ECHO Subnet Changed.....  
timeout 2  
@ECHO Gateway Changed....  
timeout 2
```

Anyone know how to do this with the timeout command or another command.. I'm just looking for it to look like it's changing each area 1 at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul
```

The `> nul` part redirects the output to the Null device, hence suppressing it. The `/NOBREAK` option prevents the wait time to be interrupted by any key presses.

Answer (score 2):

Remove output using  > nul

```
timeout /t 10 > nul
```

Answer (score 0):

solutions based on TIMEOUT don't work when TIMEOUT is executed in background batch command (.cmd or .bat) files

In this case, the TIMEOUT command exits without the expected pause/sleep, and returns

```
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately
```

The solution proposed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/timeout-command-run-batch-job-exits-immediately-and-returns-error-input-redirection-not-supported-exiting-process-immediately) is to use

```
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1
```

for a delay of 10 seconds. (This doesn't generate any network trafic)